# get activity from facebook with PHP

Tags: php, facebook

In JavaScript is http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Here are activities from Facebook Fan Page. 
Is possible to get these activity with PHP? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Your steps will be:

Create a Facebook app to use as a connector here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps. You'll need the app ID and secret.

Download the PHP SDK from here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/ and put it somewhere accessible to your program.

Use code like this. Everything in ALL_CAPS should be replaced by your specific values:

```
 <?php
 require('/PATH_TO_SDK/facebook.php');

 $config = array(
  'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
 );

 $facebook = new Facebook($config);
 $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/YOUR_PAGE_NAME_OR_ID/feed', 'GET);

 sprintf('<pre>%s</pre>', print_r($ret_obj, true));
```

Comment: thanks, and where is the list with others elements? /feed is only one element to get?

Comment: `/feed` should get you everything that is posted on a user's or page's wall.

Comment: thanks, but are others options? where is documentations for this? :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, you have to call the Graph API and crawl your fanpage.
Here is the example with official tool :
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=104958162837%2Fposts

Comment: from where i must get "104958162837"?

Comment: In querying the Graph API to, with the page namespace, for example for http://www.facebook.com/Google : 

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=Google